# Cannot get Pandas to concat/append

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I'm trying to parse a website's tables and I'm pretty noobish still. For each link only the second table/dataframe is appended to the SS. There are multiple links and therefore it requires a while loop. Using what little I could find only I am just stuck with this which Im pretty sure is totally off:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
a=1
alist = []
writer = ExcelWriter('name.xlsx')
def dffunc():
    dfs = pd.read_html('http://websitepath{}.htm'.format(a))
    df = dfs[1]
    alist.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    alist = pd.concat(df, axis=0)


while a<9:
    dffunc()
    a+=1
alist.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

df=dfs[1] takes the second table in the list. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

old:

```
df = dfs[1]
alist.append(df,ignore_index=True)
alist = pd.concat(df, axis=0)
```

- You're appending the 2nd table in the dfs collection to global alist
- You're assigning the 2nd table in the dfs collection to alist, undoing all previous steps
- Operating on a global var that is written to file once at the end of the loop defeats the purpose of your loop given second bullet; alist will only ever take on the value of the 2nd table in the last query when you write to file

new:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('name.xlsx')
writer_kwargs = {'index': False}

A = 9

def dffunc(a):
    dfs = pd.read_html('http://websitepath{}.htm'.format(a))
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)

def dfhandler(df, writer, **kwargs):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=a, **kwargs)

for a in xrange(1, A):
    dfhandler(dffunc(a), writer, **writer_kwargs)

writer.save()
```

Comment: This code doesnt work for me. Though I do agree there is scope problems that I'm not sure how to solve, a lot of the code is hodge podge from the method described by others and what my code was to begin with. Thank you for your help so far